# Using different ram in 2 free slots

Tags: memory

I have the old version of hyperx fury in my pc at the moment in their correct channel to run in dual channel mode (2x4gb hyperx blu kit ([This kit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4f5V.png)) running at 1600 MHz However these sticks were discontinued but still are running perfectly fine, I was wondering if it is possible to slot in a new ram kit with identical specs say if the new fury kit had these specs) in the other channels or would this lead to problems or if i wanted a bump in capacity would i have to get a whole new kit?

http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/KHX1600C9D3B1K2_8GX.pdf (specification sheet)

Comment: Only through latency and timing as far as i can see, will these setting need to be changed in the bios or would the motherboard automatically change them?

Comment: Your follow-up question has been answered several times here.

Comment: Ok  sorry I'm new to this i was just asking to make sure. Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

it will work even if you put in RAM with different frequency characteristic, but actual working frequency will align with the lowest among your RAM sticks.

however you must take into consideration your motherboard compatibility list, for example for [ASUS Z97-WS](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z97WS/specifications/).
also there are Memory Qualified Vendors Lists like that one - http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1150/H87M-E/H87_Series_Memory_QVL_list_Report.pdf

vendor claims those RAM stick will work in specified motherboard for sure.

thou this is not **100%** guarantee they will work - in the Internet are stories when nothing works.

in your case new kit with the identical specs will work.